# Xmlns namespace JavaScript deletion

Tags: javascript, serialization, xml-namespaces

**This is my code:**

```
var doc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null); 
var msg = document.createElement('message');
doc.appendChild(msg);
xml_serial = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(doc);
```

**And I get this output:**

```
    <message xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> </message>
```

And my wish is to prevent the namespace, so I want something like this:

```
    <message> </message>
```

How can I prevent or delete the namespace?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the `.createElement`-method on the newly generated `doc`, not the document the code is embedded in.

```
var doc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null); 
var msg = doc.createElement('message');
```